# Kubuntu 20.04 desktop wallpaper always displays only 1/4 of screen

Tags: kubuntu, kde, display-resolution, desktop-background, plasma

I have a problem with a Kubuntu user. I have two users and the problem only occurs for the one.

When I log in to the user, the desktop wallpaper always displays in the top left corner at about 25% size. It is scaled down with the correct aspect ratio. If I change the image, the problem persists. It happens if the image is the native res of the monitor, or if it isn't.

To fix it I must go into display configuration and toggle the resolution to a different size and then back again.

Once I log out and log back in again, the problem is back.

Thanks for any help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is more of a question to post on the [KDE Forum](https://forum.kde.org/). What is your KDE version? My Kubuntu 20.04 Display Configuration menu has the option to save the settings for a 'For only this specific display arrangement' or 'For any display arrangement'.

Have you tried tweaking those settings? Do you actually change the displays or have multiple monitors?